# how to deploy to google app engine. gives : POST https://xxx.appspot.com/vendor/sms.php 500 () error

Tags: php, google-app-engine

starting index html and all static files works goo. I can deploy static files but for php, first I met  404 eror, but after all I changed the app.yaml as:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 2
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /(.*).php 
  script: \1.php

- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

Now, some php works ok. but this time some php files giving Post 500 error. Any idea ?

a part of deploy log file:

```
 "GET /images/Egg-heart-for-slider.png HTTP/1.1" 204
 "POST /vendor/sms.php HTTP/1.1" 500
 "POST /vendor/mail.php HTTP/1.1" 200
 "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200
 "GET /js/jquery.scrollex.min.js HTTP/1.1" 204
 "GET /js/jquery.scrolly.min.js HTTP/1.1" 204
 "GET /js/util/jquery.inputmask.js HTTP/1.1" 204
 "GET /js/util/inputmask.extensions.js HTTP/1.1" 204
 "GET /js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 204
 "GET /js/skel.min.js HTTP/1.1" 204
 "GET /js/util.js HTTP/1.1" 204
 "GET /js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 204
 "GET /js/util/inputmask.js HTTP/1.1" 204
 "GET /js/jstulumbal.js HTTP/1.1" 204
 "GET /js/kkvalidate.js HTTP/1.1" 204
```

Comment: To get help with this, you need to provide for information: extracts from the server log showing the full error message and any stacktrace, and the code that is failing.

Comment: Here above I add a part of deploy log files results.

Comment: You need to check the server log, not the deploy log.

Comment: says. PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() !?

Comment: I fixed with in php.ini setup. (I included a php.ini to root and declared curl_init and other necessary lib. ex. for sending mail etc. )